# #Tag for background-image but .Class not applying background-position on hover

Tags: html, css

I will have tiles that are images that link to resources. Each Tile is different and I want each element to have an ID and load the unique image using the ID. Then I want the Tile class to apply uniform behavior over the TILES. Specifically the hover function which does not seem to be working. Tried all permutations I could think of with regard to inheritance to get this to work. The other properties of Tile inherit fine however. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>DEVELOPMENT</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .Tile{
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
      height: 140px;
     /* background: url("Images/Webmail.jpg") no-repeat 0 0; 
        Obviously with the background here it works.
        All tiles will animate the same way 
        (slide background-position on :hover)
        but I have to load different images for each tile. 
        #Webmail should inherit Tile and apply the position 
        change to whatever tile is hovered over. Each tile has a unique 
        tag that loads the image.
     */
    }
    .Tile:hover{ 
      background-position: 0 -140px;
    }
    .Tile span{
      position: absolute;
      top: -999em;
    }
    #Webmail{
        background: url("Images/Webmail.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #ITEM2{
        background: url("Images/ITEM2.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #ITEM3{
        background: url("Images/ITEM3.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
</style>
</head>  
<body>
<div id="Tile_Container">
<!-- Start Row 1 -->
    <div id="Row">
        <a id="Webmail" class = "Tile" href="#" title="Webmail">
            <span>Webmail</span>
        </a>
        <a id="ITEM2" class = "Tile" href="#" title="ITEM2">
            <span>ITEM2</span>
        </a>

        <a id="ITEM3" class = "Tile" href="#" title="ITEM3">
            <span>ITEM3</span>
        </a>
    </div>      
<!-- Start Row 2 ... more rows and items-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Build a codepen or jsfiddle that reproduces the error so we can debug it for you

Comment: An `id` has more specificity than a `class`, and your class (and its `:hover` state) are defined before the id's, making the ids overwrite the class behaviour in all likelihood. Instead of changing the entire background property, change only the background image to a specific property, as it will not overwrite anything but the image source. Also, just for reference, using capitals for your class seems like a confusing idea, as well as the weird spacing and the capitalisation of your ids. Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `background:` in `#Webmail`, `#ITEM2` and `#ITEM3`. The CSS attribute `background` is a combination of all background styles like `background-position`, `background-image`, `background-repeat` and so on. Therefore, `background-position` is overridden by `background`.

To solve this problem, you can use the following snippet:

```
.Tile {
   margin: 10px;
   float: left;
   width: 160px;
   height: 140px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 0 0; /* you don't even have to specify that */
}
.Tile:hover { 
   background-position: 0 -140px;
}
.Tile span {
   position: absolute;
   top: -999em;
}

#Webmail {
   background-image: url("Images/Webmail.jpg");
}
#ITEM2 {
   background-image: url("Images/ITEM2.jpg");
}
#ITEM3 {
   background-image: url("Images/ITEM3.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `background-position` values `.Tile:hover` have less specificity than the values in `#Webmail` and so on, which means that the more specific CSS rule would take precedence regardless of the value set in the `:hover` rule.

Note that the `background` short hand property will initialize all of the background properties (such as `background-position`) to default values before apply the values specified in the `background` rule, which can lead to unexpected results if the `background` property appears after any individual background properties in a CSS rule.

You can read about how the `background` property works at:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

```css
.Tile {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.Tile:hover {
  background-position: 0 -20px;
}
.Tile span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
}
#Webmail {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
}
#ITEM2 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/140x100");
}
#ITEM3 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x120");
}
```

```html
<div id="Tile_Container">
  <!-- Start Row 1 -->
  <div id="Row">
    <a id="Webmail" class="Tile" href="#" title="Webmail"> <span>Webmail</span></a>
    <a id="ITEM2" class="Tile" href="#" title="ITEM2"> <span>ITEM2</span></a>
    <a id="ITEM3" class="Tile" href="#" title="ITEM3"> <span>ITEM3</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MrLister Updated my answer accordingly, thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to set the hover action on the .class, while the background position is set on the #id. The id has a higher specificity, hence overriding the .class:hover.

Illustration of problem:

```css
.Tile {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  height: 140px;
}

/* this here is the problem */
.Tile:hover {
  background-position: 0 -140px;
}

.Tile span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
}

#Webmail {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/160/280") no-repeat 0 0;
}

#ITEM2 {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/170/280") no-repeat 0 0;
}

#ITEM3 {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/180/280") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Tile_Container">
  <!-- Start Row 1 -->
  <div id="Row">
    <a id="Webmail" class="Tile" href="#" title="Webmail">
      <span>Webmail</span>
    </a>
    <a id="ITEM2" class="Tile" href="#" title="ITEM2">
      <span>ITEM2</span>
    </a>

    <a id="ITEM3" class="Tile" href="#" title="ITEM3">
      <span>ITEM3</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- Start Row 2 ... more rows and items-->
</div>
```

So possible solutions are:

1. Make the `:hover` rule more specific by applying it to all the ids, not the shared class.

   ```css
   .Tile {
     margin: 10px;
     float: left;
     width: 160px;
     height: 140px;
   }

   /* changed: */
   #Webmail:hover, #ITEM2:hover, #ITEM3:hover {
     background-position: 0 -140px;
   }

   .Tile span {
     position: absolute;
     top: -999em;
   }

   #Webmail {
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/160/280") no-repeat 0 0;
   }

   #ITEM2 {
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/170/280") no-repeat 0 0;
   }

   #ITEM3 {
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/180/280") no-repeat 0 0;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="Tile_Container">
     <!-- Start Row 1 -->
     <div id="Row">
       <a id="Webmail" class="Tile" href="#" title="Webmail">
         <span>Webmail</span>
       </a>
       <a id="ITEM2" class="Tile" href="#" title="ITEM2">
         <span>ITEM2</span>
       </a>

       <a id="ITEM3" class="Tile" href="#" title="ITEM3">
         <span>ITEM3</span>
       </a>
     </div>
     <!-- Start Row 2 ... more rows and items-->
   </div>
   ```
2. Or, change the ids into classes in the markup.

   ```css
   .Tile {
     margin: 10px;
     float: left;
     width: 160px;
     height: 140px;
   }

   .Tile:hover {
     background-position: 0 -140px;
   }

   .Tile span {
     position: absolute;
     top: -999em;
   }

   /* changed */
   .Webmail {
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/160/280") no-repeat 0 0;
   }

   .ITEM2 {
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/170/280") no-repeat 0 0;
   }

   .ITEM3 {
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/180/280") no-repeat 0 0;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="Tile_Container">
     <!-- Start Row 1 -->
     <div id="Row">
       <!-- changed. Note space separated classes in attribute -->
       <a class="Tile Webmail" href="#" title="Webmail">
         <span>Webmail</span>
       </a>
       <a class="Tile ITEM2" href="#" title="ITEM2">
         <span>ITEM2</span>
       </a>

       <a class="Tile ITEM3" href="#" title="ITEM3">
         <span>ITEM3</span>
       </a>
     </div>
     <!-- Start Row 2 ... more rows and items-->
   </div>
   ```

Comment: @MarcAudet I was wondering the same thing. If the downvoter would care to explain, maybe we can work out a deal whereby you can get your rep point back.